# Trouble connecting Python socketio server to node js socketio client

Tags: python, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm having a lot of difficulty with a very simple task. I'm attempting to set up a socket.io client in node js, which should then communicate with a local socket.io server setup in python (using the python bindings [here](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io). The issue I'm having is the server is detecting the client, but the client never seems to receive the 'connect' event. I suspect this is an issue with the way I've deployed the server asynchronously, but I'm really not sure. The code for each file is below:

#### server.py

```
import socketio
from aiohttp import web

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 10001

# create a Socket.IO server
sio = socketio.AsyncServer(async_mode='aiohttp', logger=True, engineio_logger=True)

app = web.Application()
sio.attach(app)

@sio.on('connect')
def connect(sid, environ):
    print('connect ', sid)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    web.run_app(app, host=HOST, port=PORT)
```

#### client.js

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');

const HOST = '127.0.0.1';
const PORT = '10001';

const socket = io(`http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
console.log('Socket instantiated!');

socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log(`socket connected: ${socket.connected}`);
});
```

The output I would expect is to see the server print out that the client has connected, and then for the client to print out that it has connected too. *However*, the client never seems to receive the 'connect' event, so never prints anything to the console.

Finally, an example of the server's output is:

```
Server initialized for aiohttp.
======== Running on http://127.0.0.1:10001 ========
(Press CTRL+C to quit)
1c17586e4c7e49b48abefea2fba460e6: Sending packet OPEN data {'sid': '1c17586e4c7e49b48abefea2fba460e6', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingTimeout': 60000, 'pingInterval': 25000}
connect  1c17586e4c7e49b48abefea2fba460e6
1c17586e4c7e49b48abefea2fba460e6: Sending packet MESSAGE data 0
```

While the client's output is annoyingly just

```
$ node mySocket.js
Socket instantiated!
```

and then it just hangs doing nothing.

I'm clearly misunderstanding something here, so thank you in advance!

### Small update

I quickly tested using the python socketio client, and succesfully got an actual connection, so this should narrow it down to something I've done in the JS client.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I ended up downgrading from socket.io-client 3.00 (did not see there was this major release 3 days ago) back to 2.3.1, and everything started working again! However, based on the lack of issues listed on [Github](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues), I'm guessing this is not a bug that is affecting everyone.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I spent a lot of time debugging this issue. Then I downgraded to 2.3.1 which fixed it for me.